# Could there be a number n greater than 2 such that $(n^p-1)/(n-1)$ is prime iff $2^p-1$ is?

Tags: number-theory

It seems unlikely to be true, but pretty interesting if it were true. Can anyone prove it one way or another? Some background: If $2^p-1$ is to be prime, then p is necessarily prime, and then $2^p-1$ is then called a Mersenne prime, Mp. Even when p is prime, $2^p-1$ is usually composite. There are only 51 Mersenne primes known, and they get pretty few and far between as p gets larger. To explain my title question a bit more, suppose some number like 7,654,321 were such that $[(7654321)^p-1]/(7654320)$ were prime for exactly the same primes p for which$2^p-1$ were prime. Then my question would have a yes answer.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write the formulas.

Comment: I do not think that we can find a number and prove it for it, on the other hand, we probably can find a number such that the first $51$ exponents coincide. My guess is that there is no such number, but I think a decision is out of reach.

Comment: One argument against such a number is that the generalized mersenne numbers are always larger than the corresponding mersenne number. This makes the chance for large prime exponents much smaller that we find a prime. If we assume that infinite many mersenne primes exist, this would give a heuristic.

Comment: The numbers $(n^k-1)/(n-1)$ are also known as the repunits in base $n$. So, the question is asking whether there is a base $n$ for which the lengths of prime repunits in bases $2$ and $n$ coincide.